# Trouble with PERC H330 RAID controller recognizing drives

Tags: raid, dell, dell-perc, seagate

I have a PERC H330 RAID controller with 3 Seagate ST4000NM0034 drives, and the controller does not appear to be recognizing the drives. It does not show up in the CTRL+R screens anywhere and I'm getting concerned the cabling or card is bad. Any suggestions?

Comment: Call Dell support.

Comment: Can't afford it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't see the Ctrl+R screen, that's not going to be a cabling issue. A PERC should still show up in the BIOS regardless of whether any physical disks are connected/detected.
Check your card's seating, verify you're using a PCI slot that can provide enough power, maybe check whether the card is even compatible with the server you've put it in... standard PCI card troubleshooting.
Wouldn't hurt to heed @yoonix's words and just call Dell support if that's an option for you (if you have a warranty currently active).

Comment: CTRL+R does show up, the PDs do not.

Comment: Ah, misunderstood your wording. Try reseating the cabling to the H330? Make sure the drives are getting power? What type of server is this in?

Comment: It's in a custom built home server. I'm guessing part of the problem is the card isn't on a real server motherboard/cpu combo and it just straight up doesn't like the mobo, because I'm at a total loss for why the drives won't even spin up. I've tried switching cables, reseating, just about everything.

Comment: Moving this to comment, accidental extra answer: "What type of cable are you connecting with? If you're able to boot into the PERC BIOS, that should get you past any possible issues with the system BIOS since the H330 is just communicating directly with the drives at that point." Response was "It's a breakout cable that has one connector on one end and 4 flying leads on the other end that terminate to the SAS combined power/data. The power leads plug into the leads from the PSU."

Comment: Are you using SAS or SATA drives in the server? Have you tried powering up with just one drive connected to make sure the others aren't just pulling too much power?

Comment: SAS drives. I haven't tried powering one up, that's a good idea. I'll try that next. Thanks!